# titanium navigationGroup for both ios and android

Tags: android, ios, navigation, titanium

i am currently working on the code below and the code below is an ios navigationGroup in titanium. I am trying to make it or both ios and android but it seems complicated. How can i make it for both ios and android.

```
 var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow();



        var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

            backgroundColor: 'white',

            barColor: '#336699'

        });



        var win3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

            backgroundColor: 'white',

            barColor: '#336699',

            title: 'Register'

        });



        var win4 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

            backgroundColor: 'white',

            barColor: '#336699',

            title: 'Sign in'

        });





        //create view1

        var view1 = Titanium.UI.createView();



        //create label1

        var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({

        text: 'Welcome',

        height: 40,

        width: 250,

        top: 100,

        color: '#336699'

        });





        //create button1

        var button1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({

            title: 'Register',

            height: 35,

            width: 100,

            top: 210

        });



        button1.addEventListener('click', function(){

            nav.open(win3);

        });



        var nav = Titanium.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({

           window: win2

        });





        //create view2

        var view2 = Titanium.UI.createView();



        //create label2

        var label2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({


        height: 45,

        width: 200,

        top: 145,

        color: '#336699'

        });





        //create button2

        var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({

            title: 'Sign in',

            height: 35,

            width: 100,

            top: 250

        });



        button2.addEventListener('click', function(){

            nav.open(win4, {animated:true});

        });



        var nav = Titanium.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({

           window: win2

        });







        view2.add(button1);

        view1.add(label1);

        win2.add(view1);



        view2.add(button2);

        view2.add(label2);

        win2.add(view2);



        win1.add(nav);

        win1.open();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530946/navigationgroup-android-in-titanium

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of modules out on Git for cross-platform NavigationGroups, like https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/TiCrossPlatformNavigationGroup.
You can also search for "Titanium Navigation" on Git, there is more, see what fits your needs. I have not used one of them personally, so it is rather a hint than an advice.
Besides that, please note that NavigationGroups are **deprecated** with the latest Titanium SDK and will not be in 3.2.0. So make sure to use **NavigationWindows** instead.